# Can't assess an array element after building array - a var_dump confirms element is there

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing some login code for an external app.

Currently it is sending information via GET. The information is encoded, the server decodes the info and builds into a decoded array which I can use to auth the user.

The issue is for some reason I can't access the array element, when I know it's there. I use a var_dump to confirm.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function getNonDecodedParameters(& $a) {
  foreach (explode ("&", $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) as $q) {
    $p = explode ('=', $q, 2);
    $a[$p[0]] = isset ($p[1]) ? $p[1] : '';
  }  
}

function decode_array(&$encyrptArray, &$outputArray) {

    foreach($encyrptArray as $encrpyKey=>$encrpyValue) {
        $newKey = decode_my_mt4_string($encrpyKey);
        $newVal = decode_my_mt4_string($encrpyValue);

        $outputArray[$newKey] = $newVal;                
    }   
}

//init arrays
$inputs = array();
$decoded = array();

//manually build array from query string
//bypassing $_GET because $_GET does auto urldecode()
getNonDecodedParameters($inputs);

//decode data into new array
decode_array($inputs, $decoded);

//var dump
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($inputs);
echo '<br />';
echo 'Decoded array';
echo '<br />';
var_dump($decoded);
echo '</pre>';

//try access specific array element
printf('$decoded["cname"] = %s', $decoded['cname']);
```

The var_dump shows this is working, but for some reason when I call the element directly, a php error is thrown saying it doesn't exist???

```
array(3) {
  ["d3JfbG9naW4A"]=>
  string(12) "dGVzdHVzZXIA"
  ["cGFzcwA%3D"]=>
  string(12) "dGVzdHBhc3MA"
  ["Y25hbWUA"]=>
  string(14) "REFaV0FSRQA%3D"
}

Decoded array
array(3) {
  ["wr_login"]=>
  string(9) "testuser"
  ["pass"]=>
  string(9) "testpass"
  ["cname"]=>
  string(8) "DAZWARE"
}

Notice: Undefined index: cname in /home/website/test2.php on line 58
$decoded["cname"] =
```

I really can't think of any reason why this isn't working. Couldn't this be an issue with the server?

Comment: Could you show which is the exact line throwing the error?  Which is line 58?

Comment: Probably this one

printf('$decoded["cname"] = %s', $decoded['cname']);

Comment: It is the printf line.

Comment: Tried accessing it by index instead of "header"?

Comment: //try access by index number
printf('$decoded[2] = %s', $decoded[2]); provides same error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

Just to give you back the time and follow up what happened here.

The error in the variable name was not the problem, just a typo I made here.

I was encoding with base64 and sending that data to the php script. When I used base64_decode(), it would spit out the right string, but also junk bytes that was corrupting all the variable names.

The problem was a bad base 64 encoder from the external program I was using.

Thank you all for taking the time to help me here.