# Can't read string variables after using base64_decode() in PHP

Tags: php

I've been pulling my hair out all day with some broken code. I posted a question early, but I've narrowed down the problem to the specific issue.

Previous question: [Can't assess an array element after building array - a var_dump confirms element is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976654/cant-assess-an-array-element-after-building-array-a-var-dump-confirms-element)

Now the issue is with the base64 decode function. It is meant to return a string, but whenever you try to read the string it doesn't work.

See this simple test code...

error_reporting(E_ALL);

```
$encoded = base64_encode('my encrypted text');
$decoded = base64_decode($encoded, true);

echo "<br />";
printf('my encrypted text -> encoded to base64 = %s', $encoded);
echo "<br />";
printf('%s from base64 = %s', $endcoded, $decoded);
echo "<br />";
printf('calling $decoded to read string: result = %s', $decoded);
```

Here is the result

```
my encrypted text -> encoded to base64 = bXkgZW5jcnlwdGVkIHRleHQ=

Notice: Undefined variable: endcoded in /home/website/base64test.php on line 10
from base64 = my encrypted text
calling $decoded to read string: result = my encrypted text
```

Line 10 is this:

```
printf('%s from base64 = %s', $endcoded, $decoded);
```

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something.

How are you meant to read the result from the base64_decode() function after it has been stored in a variable.

Comment: `s/endcoded/encoded`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: en**d**coded:

```
printf('%s from base64 = %s', $endcoded, $decoded);
//-------------------------------^
```

Should be

```
printf('%s from base64 = %s', $encoded, $decoded);
//-------------------------------^
```

Comment: Thanks @Phil. Apparently Stack Overflow doesn't think having a monospace font it important on mobile view. I didn't realize how far off it was until I saw your edit.

Comment: Hehe, I'd guessed it was from a mobile

Answer (score -1):

Check typo of `$endcoded`,

```
printf('%s from base64 = %s', $encoded, $decoded);
```

Comment: What's the point in adding an answer that says the same thing as a previous, existing answer?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, is there ant restriction on adding answer, if already provided answer is similar or if any answer is marked as accepted?

Comment: There is no restriction. Feel free to waste your time, and that of the OP, as well as to be down-voted.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, No problem man, don't you think i utilized my time to understand problem. By the way thanks for your down vote.